# Efficient and fast way to parse a string with different languages

Tags: c#, regex, string, list, rest

I have a string something like (generated via Google Transliterate REST call, and transliterated into **2** languages):

> " This world is beautiful and  थिस    वर्ल्ड    इस    बेऔतिफुल    एंड 
>   থিস    বর্ল্ড    ইস    বিয়াউতিফুল    আন্দ  amazingly mysterious 
>   अमज़िन्ग्ली    म्य्स्तेरिऔस    আমাজিন্গ্লি    ম্য্স্তেরীয়ুস  "

Now Google Transliterate REST call allows **FIVE** words at a time, so I had to loop, add it to the *list* and then concatenate the string. That's why we see that each CHUNK (of **each** language) is of **5** words. The total number of words is **7** words, so first **5** (`This world is beautiful and`) lies before rest **2** (`amazingly mysterious`) later.

How do I most efficiently parse the sentence such that I get something like:

> This world is beautiful and amazingly mysterious थिस    वर्ल्ड    इस   बेऔतिफुल   एंड अमज़िन्ग्ली    म्य्स्तेरिऔस থিস    বর্ল্ড    ইস  বিয়াউতিফুল    আন্দ   আমাজিন্গ্লি    ম্য্স্তেরীয়ুস

Since the *length* of sentence, and the *number* of languages it can be converted into can be dynamic, may be using *lists of each language can work*, and then concatenated later?

I used an approach where I transliterated each word, one at a time, it works well, but too slow as it increases the number of calls to the API.

Can someone help me with an efficient (and dynamic) implementation of such a scenario? Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One list per language is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your message. I understand that, and that's what I was thinking but can you help in writing the logic? thanks.

Comment: @DevDreamer: That's your job as a developer :-) Besides, I don't know anything about your application, existing structure etc.

Comment: Thanks for your message. I think I'll end up with a non-efficient logic, that's why seeking help. And, the task is to convert the mixed language sentence into properly clustered one. I'll try to try though. Thanks.

Comment: I finally implemented that. But man, what an exercise of brain that was!

Comment: @DevDreamer: I am sure you are very proud that you did it yourself, without much help, aren't you? That's what the real fun is about software development: Solving all those little problems.

Comment: so true. Thank you for encouraging me to do it on my own. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean different character ASCII code by different languages, you can use this answer here:

[Regular expression Spanish and Arabic words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881765/regular-expression-spanish-and-arabic-words)

Comment: thanks for your message, but the solution is using JavaScript. While I am using C#.

Comment: they both use PCRE as I know as regex engine.

Answer (score 0):

Pay for google translate's API and then your length restriction goes up to 5,000 characters per request https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/faq

Also, yes, as Daniel has said - grouping the text by language will be necessary

Comment: thanks for your message, but I am using the "Transliterate" API.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a work out, correct me if i misinterpret your question

```
string statement = "This world is beautiful and थिस वर्ल्ड इस बेऔतिफुल एंड থিস বর্ল্ড ইস বিয়াউতিফুল আন্দ amazingly mysterious अमज़िन्ग्ली म्य्स्तेरिऔस আমাজিন্গ্লি ম্য্স্তেরীয়ুস ";
            string otherLangStmt = statement;

            MatchCollection matchCollection =   Regex.Matches(statement, "([a-zA-Z]+)");
            string result = "";
            foreach (Match match in matchCollection)
            {
                if (match.Groups.Count > 0)
                {
                    result += match.Groups[0].Value + " ";
                    otherLangStmt = otherLangStmt.Replace(match.Groups[0].Value, string.Empty);
                }                
            }
            otherLangStmt = Regex.Replace(otherLangStmt.Trim(), "[\\s]", " ");

            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.WriteLine(otherLangStmt);
```

Comment: thanks. That can be the first step, but what I want is a list of statements, where [0] is English, [1] is Hindi, [2] is Bengali. Through your method, I would retrieve the English, but Hindi and Bengali stay as it is. Thanks for help.

Comment: How will you identify its a Hindi or Bengali? in terms of computer's point of view?

Comment: I think its not about identifying Hindi or Bengali, its more dependent on the pattern in which I am getting the result. And parse the sentence on the basis of which. Thanks.

Comment: I have to rephrase my sentence a bit :). we know that its english, hindi, etc., but i want to know how to let computer to understand that this is different language?

Comment: that is not required, there's a pattern, and we need to grab the words placed at that particular location. Computer does not have to understand whether its Bengali or Hindi.

Comment: I'm not sure about it, so if you come across any thing let me know. :)