# How to restrict Chinese characters in a textbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, regex-negation

I have a multilingual website, where I want to restrict typing of other language characters (especially Chinese) using a regular expression. Can someone please give me an example how to implement this.

Fiddle:

`$(".textTest input").keyup(function () {
    if ($(this).val().match(/^[\u4E00-\u9FFF\u3400-\u4DFF\uF900-\uFAFF]+$/g)) {
        alert('Chinese character sets');
    }
    else alert('English');
});`

http://jsfiddle.net/srikanth1818/ofkhsr9x/

Comment: It may be easier to whitelist characters you want to allow rather than blacklisting huge portions of _UTF_

Comment: show this => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340719/regex-to-remove-non-letter-characters-but-keep-accented-letters

Comment: What does "other language" mean in the context of a multi-lingual site? Not English?

Comment: I mean chinese, spanish, etc.,

Comment: Yeah, right, those are human languages. What languages are *not* acceptable for you app? And... why? Is it okay if I type a Spanish sentence that only has English characters? What's the ultimate goal?

Comment: Yes, when I am in en-GB culture, my app should not allow spanish, chinese characters. when I am in zn-TW culture, it can allow enligsh. Thats not a problem.

Comment: @Sriks. Remember that English also borrows words from other languages. `apartheid` for example. Be very careful with restricting characters.

Comment: @Mouser. Ok, Thanks once agiain :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were going in the right direction with the regex. This code below checks for the Chinese characters sets in Unicode.

```
$(".textTest input").keyup(function () {
    if ($(this).val().match(/[\u4E00-\u9FFF\u3400-\u4DFF\uF900-\uFAFF]+/g)) {
        alert('Chinese character sets');
    }
    else alert('English');
});
```

More information can be found here:

[What's the complete range for Chinese characters in Unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366068/whats-the-complete-range-for-chinese-characters-in-unicode)

Comment: Here even if I enter, "as" as text, it alerts as "Chinese character sets".. I have tried for "as供應商", this also alerts the same.

Comment: Hi Mouser, I have tried. Not working :(  
Please find the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/srikanth1818/ofkhsr9x/

Comment: @Sriks It's working perfectly for me now, deleted beginning `^` and end `$` of string: http://jsfiddle.net/ofkhsr9x/1/

Comment: Thanks @Mouser.. Its working by deleting ^ and $. Thanks a lot :)