# Include multiple character sets in regex JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working on FormCheck
http://mootools.floor.ch/docs/formcheck/files/formcheck-js.html
 and just fund out that it has issues with other characters except a-z  for example :филми
you can try it on their demo  under alpha 
http://mootools.floor.ch/en/demos/formcheck/

now I am making a multilingual form that works fine but my verification fails when somone starts typing with special chars.

long story short , this is

alpha regex

```
alpha: /^[a-z ._-]+$/i
```

how can I modify it to include any alpha chars?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test if string contains only letters (a-z + é ü ö ê å ø etc..)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013451/test-if-string-contains-only-letters-a-z-e-u-o-e-a-o-etc)

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [XRegExp Unicode plugin](http://xregexp.com/plugins/).  With that library you could do something like this:

```javascript
var unicodeWord = XRegExp("^\\p{L}+$");
// \p{L} matches any "letter" codepoint.
unicodeWord.test('филми'); // true
unicodeWord.test('movies'); // true
unicodeWord.test('!@#$'); // false
```