# How to find the number pattern in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

From My database I'll get two kinds of numbers

1. 1234
2. a1234z1

We'll call second type of number as special type. How to detect those kind of numbers. for ex like

`isSpecialNumber("a1234z1")` should return `true` or `false`.

How can I do that in Javascript ?

Comment: Do your special numbers follow a fixed format?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: What kind of number is a1234z1? It doesn't look very numeric to me...?

Comment: Yes, it is always like a1234z1 format

Comment: Check if your number contains alphabets: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783196/how-to-check-in-javascript-that-a-string-contains-alphabetical-characters

Comment: It's very simple, but before that you've to show what you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

You could just test if its a number:

```
isNaN("a1234z1");
```

unless you need it to be that exact format then a regex would be needed.