# javascript regular expression allow name with one space and special Alphabets

Tags: javascript, regex

how to write regular expression allow name with one space and special Alphabets?
I tried with this `[a-zA-Z]+(?:(?:\. |[' ])[a-zA-Z]+)*` but not working for me,

example string **Björk Guðmundsdóttir**

Comment: Is that space mandatory or optional?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen optional only

Comment: OK, and what are "special" alphabets?  I would assume it's a special edition of breakfast cereal, unless you tell me otherwise.

Comment: https://shinesolutions.com/2018/01/08/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names-with-examples/

Comment: Use `/^\S+\s\S+$/`

Answer (score 0):

You may try something along these lines:

```
^(?!.*[ ].*[ ])[ A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]+$
```

The first negative lookahead asserts that we do *not* find two spaces in the name.  This implies that at most one space is present (or no spaces at all).  Then, we match any number of alphabets, with most accented letters included.  Spaces can also be matched, but the lookahead would already ensure that at most one space can be present.

### Demo

Comment: @techie18 Sorry, I had a typo which is fixed now.

Answer (score -1):

Use this one:

```js
[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u00ff]*[ ]{1}[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u00ff]*
```

[Answer from other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013451/test-if-string-contains-only-letters-a-z-%C3%A9-%C3%BC-%C3%B6-%C3%AA-%C3%A5-%C3%B8-etc)

Comment: Replace {1} with ? sign for 0 or 1 space included.

[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u00ff]*\s?[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u00ff]*